# Может ли быть запятая в аббревиатуре?

Tags: пунктуация, аббревиатуры

В названии организации есть запятая. Ставится ли запятая в аббревиатуре?

Comment: А Вы пример приведите.

Answer (score 2):

В аббревиатурах не ставятся ни точки, ни запятые. Аббревиатура -  сложносокращённое слово, а пунктуационные знаки внутри слова не ставятся, они разделяют отдельные слова.

Answer (score 1):

Так как Вы не "обозначили" название организации, предложу Вам *известный* пример - как образец. Из него чётко видно, что ***никаких запятых в аббревиатурах нет и быть не может:***

**СПбГУ ИТМО** - **С**анкт-**П**етер**б**ургский **г**осударственный **у**ниверситет **и**нформационных **т**ехнологий **,** **м**еханики и **о**птики